# How to use custom pattern in calendar properly?(jsf/primefaces)

Tags: jsf, primefaces, jsf-2.2

I tried below code:(*for: Date timeValue; //in backing bean*)

```
<p:calendar id="time" value="#{MB.timeValue}" locale="tr"
        pattern="dd MMM, yyyy, EEE, HH:mm"  />
```

but when I am saving this value, I get this error:

> '27 May, 2015, Ça, 12:00:00' could not be understood as a date and time.

I tried to set default timezone is system timezone in web.xml

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.DATETIMECONVERTER_DEFAULT_TIMEZONE_IS_SYSTEM_TIMEZONE</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param>
```

and I use locale translation javascript file for "tr".How can I use custom pattern?(calendar works fine with default pattern)Thanks in advance.

Comment: no, not at all.he can solved with by "mode" attribute.but i dont.i dont use minDate or any other attr. something like this.I examined his question before I open the this question.in short, I wrote what I tried above.Thank you for comment @BalusC

Comment: Do you have set `mask="true"`? Try `mask="false"`

Answer (score 0):

I think you need a proper converter for your custom date pattern. Try the following:

```
<p:calendar id="time" value="#{MB.timeValue}" locale="tr" pattern="dd MMM, yyyy, EEE, HH:mm">
    <f:convertDateTime pattern="dd MMM, yyyy, EEE, HH:mm"/>
</p:calendar>
```

Hope this works.

Comment: @erginduran, you probably need to specify `locale` in `f:convertDateTime` too.